# Jobtitle in addressbook

Tags: objective-c, addressbook

I am doing sample address book application, i am able to print firstname, lastname. But job title was not showing.
The sample code which i used is here,

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)thisPerson {


myText.text = [NSString stringWithString:@"Selected Contact:"];

myText.text = [myText.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@",
               (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(thisPerson)];

ABMutableMultiValueRef thisJob = ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonJobTitleProperty);
if (thisJob != NULL) {
    for (int k = 0; k < ABMultiValueGetCount(thisJob) ; k++) {
        myText.text = [myText.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@: %@",
                       (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(thisJob, k),
                       (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(thisJob, k)];

    }
}
```

Can any one help me for this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: sorr. Actually i need Company name also with firstname & lastname.

Comment: Hi, for company name i wrote code like ABMutableMultiValueRef thisCompany = ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
 if (thisCompany != NULL) {
  for (int j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(thisCompany) ; j++) {
   myText.text = [myText.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@: %@\n",
         (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(thisCompany, j),
         (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(thisCompany, j)];
   
  }
 }
But i am not getting company name. Where i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> `ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonJobTitleProperty);`

retuns CFStringRef not ABMutableMultiValueRef.

```
- (NSString *)jobTitleAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    return (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonJobTitleProperty);
}
```

Comment: kABPersonDepartmentProperty, kABPersonOrganizationProperty are the same return type.